# Vim: report error on a single line

Tags: vim

When an error is raised inside a Vimscript function, Vim reports an error in the following format:

```
Error detected while processing function <SNR>My_Function:
line    X:
EXXX: Error Message Here
```

This is very distracting.  Ideally, I would like this to be formatted in some way to fit on a single line, but if that's not possible, then I just want the last EXXX line with the actual error.  Is it possible to change this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't like that behavior neither, but it is how it is, and cannot be changed.

Your functions need to `:catch` any errors, and convert this into the desired one-line error message:

```
function! s:My_Function()
    try
        " commands here
    catch /^Vim\%((\a\+)\)\=:/
        echohl ErrorMsg
        echomsg substitute(v:exception, '^\CVim\%((\a\+)\)\=:', '', '')
        echohl None
    endtry
endfunction
```

This is how most plugins handle it. The behavior isn't completely like that of built-in commands, though: The error is effectively "swallowed", and subsequent commands (e.g. in a sequence `cmd1 | call <SID>My_Function() | cmd3`) will be executed despite the error. For most uses this is okay, and most users probably are even unaware of this.

#### better alternative

To make the custom command behave like a built-in one, the error message needs to be returned to the custom command or mapping, and `:echoerr`'d there. In my [ingo-library plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4433), I have corresponding helper functions:

```
function! s:My_Function()
    try
        " commands here
        return 1    " Success
    catch /^Vim\%((\a\+)\)\=:/
        call ingo#err#SetVimException()
        return 0    " Failure, use stored error message.
    endif
endfunction

if ! <SID>My_Function() | echoerr ingo#err#Get() | endif
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another approach to the problem: error messages can be decoded.

In my lh-vim-lib, I've defined [a function](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/blob/master/autoload/lh/exception.vim#L178) that decodes the last error message and displays the result in the qf-window.

Given lh-vim-lib is installed, you've to add something like

```
command! WTF call lh#exception#say_what()
```

to your `.vimrc`.

The feature by itself has been inspired from https://github.com/tweekmonster/exception.vim, the difference is that I've used stuff I've already implemented in my library plugin in order to:

- support localized messages
- support autoloaded functions, even when `#` isn't in `&isk` (which is possible depending on the settings associated to the current filetype/buffer)
- have as few loops as possible
- factorize code with my [logging](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/blob/master/doc/Log.md), and unit testing, and [DbC](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/blob/master/doc/DbC.md) frameworks.

Near the end of the screencast I've recorded to demonstrate my Dbc framework, I've used `:WTF` to display the last error in a human friendly manner.